# Characteristic function of the normal distribution

Tags: statistics, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, normal-distribution

The standard normal distribution
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}},$$
has the characteristic function
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{itx} dx = e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$
and this can be proved by obtaining the moments.

However, is there a more direct method of proving that the standard normal has the stated characteristic function?  I got stuck on trying to show that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-it)^2} dx= \sqrt{2\pi}.$$

Comment: the standard way of proving your last equation is by Cauchy theorem (i.e. it is used to show that the integral doesn't depend on $t$; imagime integrating $e^{-x^2/2}$ over a long rectangle)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple change of variables allows you to compute $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$ for *real* $t$ and standard normal $X$,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12x^2}e^{tx}\,dx\\
&= \frac{e^{\frac12t^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12(x-t)^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac{e^{\frac12t^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12y^2}\,dy\\
&=e^{\frac12t^2}.
\end{align}
$$
Here, the substitution $y=x-t$ has been used. In fact, this identity holds for all complex $t$ as well by analytic continuation. The right hand side, $e^{\frac12t^2}$ is clearly analytic. The left hand side is analytic, as it has the derivative $\mathbb{E}[Xe^{tX}]$. The fact that you can commute differentiation and expectation follows from the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). Two analytic functions which agree on the real line must agree everywhere (by analytic continuation). So the identity holds for all complex $t$, and replacing $t$ by $it$ gives the expression you ask for.

Comment: Insightful answer. Why does the derivative E[X exp(tX)] imply that E[exp(tX)] is analytic?

Answer (score 9):

In Fristedt and Gray's *A Modern Approach to Probability*, the authors sketch a proof. Use
integration by parts and dominated convergence to show that $\beta(t)=\int f(x) e^{itx} dx$ satisfies the differential equation $\beta^\prime(t)=-t \beta(t)$ with $\beta(0)=1$. You have to justify manipulating integrals of $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions.

Answer (score 0):

First by the symmetry of the integral we have

$$\begin{aligned} & F(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \cos (t x) d x \\ & F^{\prime}(t)=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} x \sin (t x) d x\end{aligned}$$
then
$$
\begin{aligned}
& F^{\prime}(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_0^{+\infty} \sin (t x) d\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right) \\
& =-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} t \cos (t x) d x \\
& =-t F(t).
\end{aligned}
$$
And $F(0)=1$, we have $F(t)=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$.