# Characteristic function of standard normal distribution using this method.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

Lets have $f(t)$ be this characteristic function.
I am told that $f'(t)=-t \cdot f(t)$ and that this can be proven, I found using partial integration and the dominated convergence theorem. I am aware of these theorems. I unfortunately do not know how to do this. The attempts tried are not of value worth sharing.

$$X:N(0,1)$$
$$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itx}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$$

Comment: I don't understand your question. The second function you have is just $ce^{itx}$ with a real number $c$, and it does **not** satisfy $f'(t) = t f(t)$. Rather, the only functions that do are of the form $f(t) = c e^{t^2/2}$.

Comment: the question is proving that $f(t)=ce^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$

Comment: Check out what Byron Schmuland commented here, in the answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29299/characteristic-function-of-the-normal-distribution

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/270580/36150

Comment: "The attempts tried are not of value worth sharing." Hmmm...