# Inverse of a characteristic function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, characteristic-functions

I have a characterisitic function of the form   $e^{(-\alpha t + t^2)}\sum_{j=0}^\infty C_j t^j $, where $\alpha, C_j$'s are complex constants.  I am trying to find the probability distribution for this characteristic function.

Had the characteristic function just been of the form $e^{(-\alpha t + t^2)} $, the integration would have been simply

\begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(-\alpha t + t^2)} e^{-itx} dx &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(t^2 + (\alpha + ix)t)} dx \\
&= e^{(\frac{(\alpha+ix)}{2})^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(t+\frac{(\alpha+ix)}{2})^2} dx
\end{align}

Using clues from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29307/471078), I think the integral evaluates to some constant. However, having this extra term $\sum_{j=0}^\infty C_j t^j$ troubles me with the integration as I cannot proceed with the above approach.

Can you please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: It seems like you're confusing $x$ and $t$ in your integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with the $\sum_{j=0}^\infty C_j t^j$ terms is pretty straightforward, if one understands the fact that characteristic function of $\frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n}$ is $(it)^n\hat{f(t)}$