# Trick to solve an improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, normal-distribution

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i a x} e^{-b x^2} \,\mathrm d x$$

Is there any good trick to solve this type integral? I guess there's a way to make that form like $\int e^{-x^2} \,\mathrm d x$. So I could get answer in terms of $\pi$.  Is there any good trick that I can solve this  easily?

Comment: This is really not precalc; that said, my first instinct would be to substitute $u = \frac{e^{-iax}}{-ia}$

Comment: In Probability Theory this integral is essentially the 'characteristic function ' of the normal distribution. There are many ways of evaluating this integral but they all require some knowledge of complex analysis. For example, you can evaluate this when $a$ is a purely imaginary number by basic Calculus and use theorems in Complex Analysis to say what the value is when $a$ is real.

Comment: Notice that the integral is real and equals $\int\cos ax\,e^{-bx^2}dx$.

Comment: Related: [Characteristic function of the normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29299/339790)

Comment: Your integral can be seen as the Fourier transform of $e^{-bx^2}$;[it can be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149824/computing-the-gaussian-integral-with-fourier-methods?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) the Fourier transform of the gaussian is still a gaussian.

Comment: Related: [How to calculate the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/270566/339790)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we can differentiate under the integration sign,

$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}=-i\int x\,e^{-iax-bx^2/2}dx.$$ (Notice the $/2$ for convenience.)

Then we can write
$$-iaI+\frac bi\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}=\int(-ia-bx)e^{-iax-bx^2/2}dx=\left.e^{-iax-bx^2/2}dx\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=0.$$

Hence the differential equation

$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}+\frac abI=0$$

that is separable and solved by

$$I=Ce^{-a^2/2b}.$$

The integration constant can be determined by setting $a=0$,

$$C=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-bx^2/2}dx=\frac1{\sqrt b}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}dx.$$

Comment: How did you know which to use as a parameter between a and b? I really like it.

Comment: Using $b$ leads nowhere because it will introduce a factor $x^2$ when what you need is $x$ to form the derivative of $iax+bx^2/2$.

Comment: if for example the exponent of the $e^{-bx^2/2}$ was something different that required you to include an $x$ term in the differential equation for $I$. Is this legal? So for example if the DE was $-iaI + bx/i \frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \cdots = 0$.

Answer (score -1):

Trick, is that what you want?
$$
F(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{zx}e^{-bx^2}
$$
is an analytic function of $z$, so if you know it on an infinite set (such as $z \in \mathbb R$, where Rhys's change of variables works without extra effort), then you get it for free on the rest of the values of $z$.

Answer (score -3):

You have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{e^{bx^2+axi}}dx}$$
Try substituting out $u=bx^2+axi$

Comment: This is hopeless.

Comment: I cannot see this working at all. Can you take it further?